# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForXXXRelease'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I upgrade android studio version to 2.3,and gradle version to 3.3,and android gradle plugin version to 2.3.0,and buildToolsVersion version to  25.0.0,It has some problem when I use this command "**gradlew assembleRelease**" to package my application.

```
Shrinking...
Printing usage to [E:\workspace\android_source\src\app\build\outputs\mapping\XXX\release\usage.txt]...
Removing unused program classes and class elements...
  Original number of program classes: 10650
  Final number of program classes:    10247
Optimizing...
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForXXXRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForXXXRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 34.554 secs
```

but when I downgrade android gradle plugin to version 2.2.3,and buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1,It works well.

Comment: Your build tools and Gradle can be updated further. Might help

Comment: But it is up to date

Comment: No they aren't. Gradle is at 3.4 and the build-tools are greater than 25

Comment: I tried to upgrade gradle version to 3.4,but it still has problem.I found this problem because of the android gradle plugin,when I user version 2.2.3,it works well.but 2.3 has problem,I don`t know how to deal with it,maybe the next version will fix this bug.Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try `gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace` and see what the errors are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem,It is because the proguard version is too low,if we update the gradle plugin,the version is greater than 2.3.0,we must use the proguard version 5.3.2 or higher,this is how to use the high proguard version,here is two solutions:

1.Add these code in build script method of your build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  ...
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3'
    }
  }
}
```

then,repackage.

2.To download proguard.jar by this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/)
.then,create a folder in root path of your project,put the jar in this folder,add these code in your build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      flatDir{dirs 'proguard'}
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
      classpath ':proguard:'
  }
}
```

then,repackage.